# Авторизация в приложении в случае отсутствия интернета

Tags: c#, авторизация, хеширование

Существует desktop приложение Windows, авторизация в котором происходит через веб-сервис посредством токена, или с помощью логина/пароля в случае его отсутствия.

Требуется реализовать возможность авторизации в приложении, в случае отсутствия онлайн соединения. Для этого, я подумываю просто хэшировать логин и пароль при успешной авторизации через интернет и отправлять их в файл, а в случае отсутствия интернет соединения, хэшировать введенные логин и пароль, и сверять с тем, что есть в файле. Если существует совпадение, то пускать в приложение.

На сколько мне известно, хэш-код нельзя дехэшировать, т.е. вернуть исходное состояние. Поэтому возникает закономерный вопрос, на сколько безопасно данное решение, или же есть что-то более эффективное?

Comment: А как быть с токеном? Если нет интернета, то с сервера он не придет и придется добавлять в desktop версию приложения методы, для генерации токена.

Comment: существует более эффективное - сверять отпечатки пальца, сверять голос пользователя, просканировать клетчатку глаза... А если серьезно, то на сколько я знаю, при логине в Windows с учеткой MS также требует, чтобы первый раз мы залогинились online, а дальше уже в режиме offline она проверяет веденный пароль с тем, который сохранился, когда пользователь входил offline. А вот как она сохраняет пароль - точно сказать не могу, но хешировать пароль для offline - это стандартная практика, и проверять потом с хешем. Ваш вопрос наверное больше заключается каким образом корректно захешировать пароль

Comment: @Nikita в соответствии с текущей архитектурой приложения, токен прежде всего нужен для безопасного обмена сообщениями с сервером. Это значит, что войдя в оффлайн режим, пользователь сможет получить свою информацию из базы данных, но при этом, не сможет общаться с сервером до тех пор, пока не будет установлено интернет соединение.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov т.е. получается данное решение является все таки безопасным. А не могли бы Вы подсказать с точки зрения хэш-алгоритмов, какие сейчас в ходу больше всего? Я слышал что SHA512 является одним из надежнейших алгоритмов, так ли это на самом деле?

Comment: @АртёмКиргизов, я вам по криптостойкости хеш функций подсказать не возьмусь, потому что не являюсь экспертом в безопасности. Может кто-то другой даст вам более компетентный ответ. Но я бы наверно капал в направлении криптографической функции, которая бы "солилась" параметром конкретной машины(привязка к железу).

Comment: А зачем вам вообще отдельный вход в приложение? Почему нельзя оставить авторизацию только для взаимодействия с сервером, а локально доверять стандартным механизмам операционной системы?

Comment: @PavelMayorov все дело в том, что приложение является многопользовательским, а данные внутри являются конфиденциальными. Поэтому, целью является не столько работа приложения в оффлайне, сколько качественная, надежная аутентификация, для предотвращения передачи приватных данных несанкционированному лицу. А вход останется один и тот же, кроме как отключения некоторых функций без интернет-подключения.

Comment: @АртёмКиргизов тогда вам нужно еще и шифрование данных, иначе злоумышленник попросту вытащит их из ваших файлов в обход проверок в приложении, причем ключ шифрования нельзя хранить на диске... Вы уверены что сможете реализовать шифрование файлов с данными качественнее чем это сделали в Microsoft?

Comment: @PavelMayorov согласен с вами, если хэшируя пароль и логин, никто не сможет их вернуть в исходное состояние, то с данными в БД посложнее, так как на данный момент используется SQLite. Не могли бы вы подробней рассказать, о "стандартных механизмах ОС" по авторизации? Во избежания дальнейшего недопонимания уточню, приложение работает под управлением UWP, поэтому некоторая часть .NET Framework недоступна, вместе с некоторыми низкоуровневыми возможностями.

Comment: @АртёмКиргизов в винде есть такая возможность как отдельные пользователи со своими профилями, логинами и паролями...

Comment: @PavelMayorov как я говорил выше, приложение является многопользовательским. Поэтому, должна быть предусмотрена возможность входа и выхода из приложения на одной учётной записи.

Comment: @АртёмКиргизов но зачем? Почему нельзя выдать всем пользователям по учетке в винде?

Comment: @PavelMayorov бизнес-требования

Comment: Вы еще имейте в виду, что если Вы просто сохраните в файле хеши логина-пароля без дополнительных ухищрений типа соли, то файл могут подменить другим, с заранее вычисленными хэшами